# Why did I get a downvote for this question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, down-votes, specific-question

This is the first time I post here but I have a very unclear issue. [This is my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743223/video-thumbnail-from-url-is-generated-on-emulator-but-not-on-real-device) on Stack Overflow. It doesn't show "no research effort" and I guess it is clear enough. Then why might I have received a downvote? I don't get it.

Comment: Apart from the downvote, if you say things like `I know this question has been asked before` and link to a question, don't you think this is a duplicate? Just a heads-up really...

Comment: @Nanne In my opinion, the updated form, at least, it is afar from beeing a duplicate. `this question has been asked before` I mean it is similar but not identic.

Comment: I disagree, but not enough to close-vote :). My opinion is that if it has been asked before, then it is duplicate. If it is not identic, then it hasn't been asked before and only looks like the other question. But the reason I pointed it out is so you might be able to avoid more negativity in your question by rewording it: it's not about what means what, but what someone else might think it means.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

People can downvote for whatever reason they like. Maybe they don't like your use of non-standard English. Maybe they don't like that you're posting a duplicate of another question and haven't distinguished your question enough from the other. Maybe they think your question is unclear. Maybe they don't like that you use Android.

My bet is on the fact that you haven't adequately described exactly what the problem is except to say "it's not working". I'd look to the comments to help you improve the question.

Comment: You're right about "People can downvote for whatever reason they like". I took your advice and edit my question, and seems that peoples changed their minds :)